# How to perform ip/date/histogram range query(like in Elasticsearch) in crateDB?

Tags: crate, cratedb

I have looked up the crateDB official documentation, but I have not found how to perform a `range` query. In Elasticsearch it is done as follows:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "aggs" : {
        "price_ranges" : {
            "range" : {
                "field" : "price",
                "ranges" : [
                    { "to" : 100.0 },
                    { "from" : 100.0, "to" : 200.0 },
                    { "from" : 200.0 }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
'


 {
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "histogram_bucket": {
            "histogram": {
                "field": "dport",
                "interval": 5000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a solution? 
thx, iqiye

Comment: Try to provide a [mcve], you'll fit SO guidelines and you're more likely to be helped

Comment: @Gsk thanks for replying.This is my first time asking questions , I'll go through the docs and review my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CrateDB doesn't support range queries in this way. It does within WHERE clauses, but not within GROUP BY clauses. While CrateDB does support percentiles https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/general/builtins/aggregation.html#percentile, it doesn't currently have any functionality to define histogram buckets and intervals.

You can, however, expose the elasticsearch API https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/0.57/configuration.html#elasticsearch-http-rest-api and issue this query that way.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a plan to support range query in CrateDB？

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but I can add it to our requested features backlog.